# Doubly Linked List adding elements

Tags: c++, list, reference

I've a uni assignment and unfortunately, encountered a problem.

I'm still struggling with pointers and references so it's quite hard for me to find a solution, even though I've searched for it for an entire day.

Here are essential parts of my code:

```
struct BuenoList
{
    int value;
    BuenoList* prev;
    BuenoList* next;
};
```

Declaration:

```
void insertNode(BuenoList*, int);
```

Definition:

```
void insertNode(BuenoList* tail, int _id)
{
    BuenoList* temp = new BuenoList;

    temp->value = _id;
    temp->prev = tail;
    tail->next = temp;
    tail = temp;
    tail->next = NULL;
}
```

Now, in main() I do this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BuenoList* BuenoListing = new BuenoList;
    BuenoListing->value = 1;
    BuenoListing->prev = NULL;
    BuenoListing->next = NULL;

    BuenoList* BuenoHead = BuenoListing;
    BuenoList* BuenoTail = BuenoListing;

    insertNode(BuenoTail, 2); // Add value 2 to the list
    insertNode(BuenoTail, 3); // Add value 3 to the list

    return 0;
}
```

Okay, so here's the problem:
When I print the list from the first element it prints like this:
1
1 2
1 3
So apparently this line

> insertNode(BuenoTail, 3);

overwrites value 2.

My guess would be that BuenoTail does not change so there must be a problem with the reference.

How can I solve this?
Print should be: 1 2 3

@EDIT

```
void deleteNode(BuenoList*& tail, int _id) // Search list for specified value and delete it
{
    BuenoList* temp = tail;

    while (temp->prev != NULL)
    {
        if (temp->value == _id) break; 
        else temp = temp->prev;
    }

    if (temp->value == _id)
    {
        temp->prev = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    else std::cout << "ERROR KEY DOES NOT EXIST\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you wanted to keep your code structure the same, I will show you two possible solutions.  In a C fashion, you can use a pointer to a pointer to update your head and tail pointers.  Or, in C++ you can pass your head and tail pointers by reference.  Personally, in C++ I would make a LinkedList class that keeps track of your head and tail nodes though.

#### Passing pointer by reference (C++)

In order to pass your pointer by reference, first change your `insertNode` declaration,

```
void insertNode(BuenoList *&tail, int _id);
```

Next, change your `insertNode` definition with the same function arguments.  That is it, your code should work now.  This minute change works, because your `tail` node in the `insertNode` function is aliased with the `tail` node in your `main` function.

#### Passing pointer by pointer (C)

I know you put a C++ tag, but you can also update your `head` and `tail` nodes using a more C like method.  First, in the main function, you will need to declare `BuenoHead` and `BuenoTail` as a pointer to a pointer.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    BuenoList* BuenoListing = new BuenoList;
    BuenoListing->value = 1;
    BuenoListing->prev = NULL;
    BuenoListing->next = NULL;

    BuenoList** BuenoHead = new BuenoList*;
    BuenoList** BuenoTail = new BuenoList*;
    *BuenoHead = BuenoListing;
    *BuenoTail = BuenoListing;

    insertNode(BuenoTail, 2); // Add value 2 to the list
    insertNode(BuenoTail, 3); // Add value 3 to the list

    return 0;
}
```

Then you need to update the `insertNode` function declaration to take a pointer to a pointer.

```
void insertNode(BuenoList** tail, int _id);
```

Then, you need to update the function definition to deference your pointer to a pointer correctly,

```
void insertNode(BuenoList** tail, int _id) 
{
    BuenoList* temp = new BuenoList;

    temp->value = _id;
    temp->prev = *tail;
    temp->next = NULL;
    (*tail)->next = temp;
    *tail = temp;
}
```

### EDIT

#### Deleting a node

You modified your question, asking for help on deleting a node.  You have several problems with your `deleteNode` function.

1. You mix `new` with `free`.  Whenever you allocate with `new`, you should correspondingly use `delete`.
2. You call `temp->prev` without checking whether `temp` could be `NULL` or not.
3. You need to change the function arguments to include your `head` pointer.  It might turn out the node you want to delete is the head of your linked list.  If so, you'll need to update the head node accordingly.
4. You need to check whether the node you are deleting is in the middle of the list, the head of the list, the tail of the list, or if is is the only node of the list.  Each of these cases requires different operations to update your linked list.

Considering this is a university assignment, I don't want to give you the full blown solution.  Here is a partially modified `deleteNode` function.  I left some parts for you to fill out though.  Hopefully that helps.  Maybe next time focus the question a bit more, so I don't have to give a partial solution.

```
void deleteNode(BuenoList*& tail, BuenoList*& head, int _id) {
    BuenoList* toDelete;
    toDelete = tail;

    // Traverse list and find node to delete
    while( ( toDelete != NULL ) && ( toDelete->value != _id ) ) {
        toDelete = toDelete->prev;
    }

    // If node not found, return
    if( toDelete == NULL ) {
        std::cout << "ERROR KEY DOES NOT EXIST\n";
        return;
    }

    // Check to see if node to delete is tail
    if( toDelete == tail ) {
        if( toDelete->prev != NULL ) {
            tail = toDelete->prev;
            tail->next = NULL;              
        } else { //Deleting only node in list
            tail = NULL;
            head = NULL;
        }
        delete toDelete;
        return;
    }

    // Check to see if node to delete is head
    if( toDelete == head ) {
        // FILL OUT WHAT TO DO HERE
        return;
    }

    // Node to delete is neither head nor tail.
    // FILL OUT WHAT TO DO HERE
    return;
}
```

Comment: Wow! This actually works! Would never think about creating *& argument! Thanks mate! : )

Comment: Umm, can you help me once again with delete function? I'm doodling with it but cant quite find how to do it correctly, I've edited main post with my delete function, see it if you are interested in helping me once again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I've filled missing pieces of code, everything works well now! Based on your examples I was able to add deleteAll function + Quick Sort algorithm : ). Many thanks once again!

Answer (score 2):

You are updating `tail` within `insertNode()`, but the updated value is not communicated back to the caller in any way. So `BuenoTail` does not change, as you suspected.

One easy way to fix that is to change your function to:

```
BuenoList *insertNode(BuenoList* tail, int _id)
```

and return the new `tail` from that function. Also change the calls to

```
BuenoTail = insertNode(BuenoTail, 2); // Add value 2 to the list
```

Comment: You can also update tail by having the function argument BuenoList** tail in the insert node function.  He would have to update the function body accordingly.  Could be useful if he wants to keep his function void.

Comment: @DavidPisani: Yes, there are many possible ways to fix this, including pointer-to-pointer, and using a reference (since this is C++). However, my suggested solution does not involve double indirection and should be easy to understand.

Comment: ^ I agree with what David said, or if he wanted to return an integer failure code should that function be expanded to be more elaborate or a boolean if it were in a class that had a failcode member.

Comment: @DavidPisani i would love to keep function void. I'm right now trying to change the body function accordingly even though I'm struggling with it

Comment: @DavidPisani if you can help me with it i would be very grateful. And I believe using a reference is preffered

Comment: @itzathis I will write up something in a bit for you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using a node structure and a list structure:

```
struct BuenoNode
{
    int value;
    BuenoNode* prev;
    BuenoNode* next;
};

struct BuenoList
{
    BuenoNode* head;
    BuenoNode* tail;
    size_t count; // having a count would be optional
}
```

The list functions would take a pointer to the list structure, such as InsertNode(BuenoList * blptr, int data); The list structure would be initialized so that both head and tail pointers == NULL, and you'll need to check for adding a node to an empty list or removing the only node in a list to end up with an empty list.